# Disable right click on treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

When click on a node of treeview, that node will be highlight then right click in the space area, current select node will be un-highlight. So all I want is disable the right click. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: what do you meant by space area?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to stop this Un-Highlighting try setting the "HideSelection" property of the tree to false.